# Maintain row ordering in chained queries

Tags: postgresql

This is all somewhat condensed to make it more understandable but I hope the gist is here. I'm really looking for some insight into how postgresql handles row sets.

I have a 'thing' table with a bunch of items in it -- each thing has a large number of attributes.  I have another table called the 'category' table.  The categories are user-defined, consisting of a name and some filters: A user can establish a new category and then define attribute filters for it.  The filters (stored in a 'filter' table) determine which items from the thing table are to be included in each category.  So each filter identifies an attribute type, and an attribute value (or in some cases a range of values but that's not really important here).

The filters *are* associated relationally with the categories (i.e. each filter has a category ID), but neither is relationally associated with the thing table. Instead I have a function to which I can pass a filter row and a thing row and it will return whether the attributes in the thing are considered to match the model attributes in the filter.

In many cases, multiple categories will match a given thing. But I only want it to show up in the output within one category. So, each category has a match-priority field. Furthermore, the resulting row set is used to organize a display, so there is a second category property that determines "display" priority. (I haven't really gotten to this part yet.)

Essentially what I want to do is (a) run a query that determines which categories each thing matches. I then want to (b) select the first category that each thing matches (lowest match priority) and drop the rest. Finally, I want to (c) re-order the result set so that they are in display-priority order.

The (a) part seems to work fine. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.foo, t.bar, <other fields> FROM (category c JOIN filter f USING (category_id))
               JOIN thing t ON fmatch(f, t)
               ORDER BY c.priority);
```

(fmatch is the function implementing the actual matching algorithm and seems to work fine).

I get a result set which correctly associates each thing with each category it ought to match based on the filters.

The next step is to weed out multiple matches. The result rows are in the correct order at the end of the above step, so I attempted to just use a "DISTINCT ON (t.foo, t.bar)" fields (there is no one field in thing guaranteed to be unique, but a composite set of fields is).

```
WITH results1 AS (<above query>)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo, bar) * FROM results1;
```

However, this step doesn't appear to maintain the order from the first query. Or in any case, while the DISTINCT ON is keeping exactly one row from the previous step, it's not always keeping the first one from the preceding row set (sometimes it does, sometimes not).

So obviously I misunderstand how postgresql is handling the result sets. I assumed that the ordering from step 1 will still be in place when I execute the "DISTINCT-ON" part in step 2, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone explain why this doesn't work? Or give me a hint how I can force it to be maintained? Or another way to implement this?

(I tried adding an "ORDER BY" and "DISTINCT ON" in the same query, but it requires that they use the same fields which doesn't make sense in my case.)

Using latest 9.6 postgresql if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Documenting for posterity...

I found a way to accomplish what I needed using a window function -- at least it appears to work reliably. My explanation as I understand it:

The first SELECT partitions the first result set into "windows" based on the unique thing attributes, orders them by category priority within the window, then the outer DISTINCT ON selects the first row in each window. Afterward, the second SELECT just sorts the resulting row set by display order.

The resulting query looks like this:

```
WITH res AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo, bar)
             c.priority, c.display, t.*,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY (foo, bar) ORDER BY priority)
        FROM (category c JOIN filter f USING (category_id))
             JOIN thing t ON fmatch(f, t))
SELECT * FROM res ORDER BY display;
```